# Problemas para reseteo de puerto COM

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, .net-core, net

buenos días.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que recibe una cadena de caracteres desde un dispositivo a través de una puerta rs232.
El proceso funciona bien, salvo que, en algún punto, se bloquea el puerto COM que estoy usando para la comunicación.
El programa (desarrollado en net core 7), detecta que el puerto está bloqueado, (por el motivo que sea), e intenta realizar un cierre del puerto y un posterior reinicio.
Acá es donde estoy teniendo problemas, ya que el puerto bloqueado, no responde al cierre y apertura a través de close y open respectivamente.

He estado intentando entonces, deshabilitar y habilitar el puerto de comunicaciones a través de diferentes formas, pero ninguna ha funcionado correctamente, ya sea por problemas con la forma de ejecución, o bien con los comandos para deshabilitar y habilitar el puerto COM

con PowerShell con Snap-In (Diagnostics.dll), acá cuando uso el Snap-In Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics, no se encuentra en la ruta especificada. supongo que puede deberse a una falta de compatibilidad con el entorno de ejecución de .NET Core 7.0.

con PowerShell mediante Gestor de Paquetes (System.Management.Automation) el problema parece ser que la versión del paquete System.Management.Automation (7.4.0) no es compatible con .NET Core 7.0.

Intente también instalando Devcon, pero a pesar de que Devcon  pudo encontrar el dispositivo usando el identificador al momento de ejecutar el disable con el id del dispositivo, no lo ejecuta. Esta es la opción con la cual he logrado mejores resultados, al menos para identificar el dispositivo, pero al hacer el disable, simplemente dice que no encuentra el dispositivo.

También probé con Mode, y acá el comando mode no deshabilita el puerto COM de ninguna manera.

por último, he estado revisando WMI (instrumentación en windows), pero el problema acá es que usando WMI se genera una excepción al intentar deshabilitar el dispositivo: System.Management.ManagementException: 'Error genérico

Se me acabaron las ideas, no se si el problema será porque el puerto al estar bloqueado no permite que se deshabilite, o resetee..
Si alguien ha trabajado antes con este tipo de problemas, y me puede ayudar, por favor.
Saludos y gracias por leer.

Comment: Mucho puntaje como para no saber que una pregunta como esta debe venir con código

Comment: pff ya sé porque se murió stackoverflow...

Comment: Porque hacen preguntas sin código donde uno tiene que adivinar como estas implementando la funcionalidad que describes??? o porque en vez de copiar y pegar el código que te están solicitando (con el único propósito de ayudarte) gastan el tiempo en comentarios sarcásticos ???

Comment: En temas de relación con hardware, ve por .`net framework` en lugar de `.net core`. Por otro lado, lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: estimado yuseff..  por si no te diste cuenta, o quiza no terminaste de leer.. no estoy pidiendo ayuda con algun codigo, si no que con ideas para resolver mi problema..  si necesitase ayuda con algo de codigo, creeme que no la pediria aca..